# Remove all occurrences with global RegExp and String.prototype.replace

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```js
function strip(match, before, after) {
  return before && after ? ' ' : ''
}

var regex = /(^|\s)(?:y|x)(\s|$)/g

var str = ('x 1 y 2 x 3 y').replace(regex, strip)
console.log(str)

str = ('x y 2 x 3 y').replace(regex, strip)
console.log(str)
```

The goal is to remove all occurrences of "x" and "y".

The first example works as expected, but the second does not.

**The requirements:**

- The solution must support removing words of any length.
- There must never be greater than 1 space between words.
- Avoid removing words that contain "x" or "y" (must be equal).

Can I work around this with `replace` or do I need a different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match the same character two times (the space character that is at the end of a match, can't be matched one more time at the beginning of next match when the substrings are consecutive).

A possible way to avoid this is to change `( |$)` to a lookahead that checks the space without consuming it. But you need to change also your approach since you have to trim eventual remaining spaces at the end or the beginning:

```
var regex = /(^|\s)(?:y|x)(?!\S)/g;
var str = 'x y 2 x 3 y'.replace(regex, '').trim();
```

`(?!\S)` means: *not followed by a non-whitespace character (that succeeds if the position is followed by a space or the end of the string)*.

---

Other way: you can match all consecutive x and y.

```
function strip(match, before, after) {
    return before && after ? ' ' : ''
}

var regex = /(^|\s)(?:y|x)(?:\s(?:y|x))*(\s|$)/g;

var str = 'x y 2 x 3 y'.replace(regex, strip);
```

---

splitting the string:

```
var str = 'x y 2 x 3 y'.split(/\s+/).filter(a => !['x', 'y'].includes(a)).join(' ');
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! Here's a jsPerf comparing the three: https://jsperf.com/strip-occurrences-of-a-word

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with 3 replace statements:

`('x y 2 x 3 y 4 x').replace(/\b[xy]\b/g, "").replace(/\b\s\s+\b/g, ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")`

EDIT: the last one can be replaced with `.trim()`

Answer (score -1):

I solved it yet another way that doesn't use trim():

`('x 1 y 2 x 3 y 4 x').replace(/(^|\s?)(?:y|x)(\s?|$)/g, strip)`

```js
function strip(match, before, after) {
  return before && after ? ' ' : ''
}

console.log("With 1: ", ('x 1 y 2 x 3 y 4 x').replace(/(^|\s?)(?:y|x)(\s?|$)/g, strip))

console.log("With 1: ", ('x y 2 x 3 y 4 x').replace(/(^|\s?)(?:y|x)(\s?|$)/g, strip))
```

Comment: That will match words that contain "x" or "y", instead of only "x" or "y".

Comment: You did not specify that in your post.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified the requirements in the question.